# How can I fill with colour particular cells in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have this code and it works fine. But the problem is that I have to make a lot of if-elif things. I need to make it in a more elegance way.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/New.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(u'И')

redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00',end_color='FFFF00',fill_type='solid')#желтый
redFill2 = PatternFill(start_color='FF4500',end_color='FF4500',fill_type='solid')#красный
redFill3 = PatternFill(start_color='FFA500',end_color='FFA500',fill_type='solid')#оранжевый
redFill4 = PatternFill(start_color='228B22',end_color='228B22',fill_type='solid')#зеленый

if ws.cell(row=2, column=4).value=='50,00%':
    ws['E2'].fill = redFill2
elif ws.cell(row=2, column=4).value=='75,00%':
    ws['E2'].fill = redFill3
elif ws.cell(row=2, column=4).value=='100,00%':
    ws['E2'].fill = redFill4

wb.save('/New.xlsx')
```

I want to create something like this :

```
def ws_f(row,column):
    if ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value=='50,0%':
        return ws.cell.fill = redFill2
    elif ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value=='75,0%':
        return ws.cell.fill=redFill3
    elif ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value=='100,0%':
        return ws.cell.fill=redFill4

ws_f(3,5)
```

But it does not work with the `def ws_f` way. Any suggestions?

Comment: What errors did you get when you tried the def ws_f way? And how did you call the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience with openpyxl, formatting functions like what you want require the worksheet to be passed in as an argument as well.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/New.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(u'И')

redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00',end_color='FFFF00',fill_type='solid')#желтый
redFill2 = PatternFill(start_color='FF4500',end_color='FF4500',fill_type='solid')#красный
redFill3 = PatternFill(start_color='FFA500',end_color='FFA500',fill_type='solid')#оранжевый
redFill4 = PatternFill(start_color='228B22',end_color='228B22',fill_type='solid')#зеленый


def ws_f(wks, row, column):
    if wks.cell(row=row, column=column).value=='50,0%':
        wks.cell(row=row,column=column).fill = redFill2
    elif wks.cell(row=row, column=column).value=='75,0%':
        wks.cell(row=row,column=column).fill = redFill3
    elif wks.cell(row=row, column=column).value=='100,0%':
        wks.cell(row=row,column=column).fill = redFill4
wsf(ws, 3, 4)
wb.save("File_out.xlsx")
```

It's also better to have the variable not shadow the outer scoped `ws` that you have above so I named it `wks`. You don't want to call `return` in the function either as the output will expect a value passed back while this formatting simply operates on the cell itself. I tested it and it worked for me. Hope this helped!